# Can't run rails server. Sass / Ruby version errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I tried to run my rails server and this was my output:

```
$ rails s
/Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2054: warning: else without rescue is useless
/Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2060: warning: else without rescue is useless
/Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2099: warning: else without rescue is useless
/Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script.rb:34:in `require': /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2050: syntax error, unexpected modifier_if (SyntaxError)
          if separator.value == 'auto'
            ^
/Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2054: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
/Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2060: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
/Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2095: syntax error, unexpected modifier_if
          if separator.value == 'auto'
            ^
/Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2099: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
/Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2885: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script.rb:34:in `<module:Script>'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script.rb:8:in `<module:Sass>'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/engine.rb:47:in `require'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/engine.rb:47:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass.rb:99:in `require'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass.rb:99:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.6/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:1:in `require'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.6/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.6/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `require'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.6/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.6/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.6/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
  from /Users/alex/Desktop/Twitter/smolbot/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/alex/Desktop/Twitter/smolbot/bin/rails:9:in `require'
  from /Users/alex/Desktop/Twitter/smolbot/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
  from /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
  from /Users/alex/Desktop/Twitter/smolbot/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:3:in `load'
  from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I looked around for an answer and I read a lot of things about my Ruby not being updated. I'm currently on 2.1.3 so i tried to update to 2.5. I ran 'rvm install ruby-2.5' and got this error:

```
$ rvm install ruby-2.5
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.13/x86_64/ruby-2.5.1.
```

I don't know if these problems are related. I really am kind of stuck and can't figure out how to get rails working. Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated!

```
My Gemfile:
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sassc-rails'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Comment: The paths (`Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/...`) in the stack trace suggest that you're using rbenv rather than rvm so wouldn't you upgrade your Ruby through rbenv? Also, you might want to switch to the sassc-rails gem since Ruby Sass is deprecated and will hit end-of-life next March.

Comment: please post your gem file.

Comment: @CryptexTechnologies

sorry for late response, i added my gemfile above